# Proxy auth using cURL when the proxy has another auth port

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a proxy where the auth part is done on another port (10001) than the normal user port (10000).

How to do the auth + the normal request in one call?

Comment: Which proxy software are you using?

Comment: None, using plain PHP with the cURL lib

Comment: Well in your question you write that you're using a proxy. As curl is not a proxy I have to stress the point that you didn't answer my question. Which proxy software are you using? Curl is just the client library, that's not the proxy. And I'm somewhat sure you didn't want to say that the proxy you're using is as well written in PHP and curl, right?

Comment: And please define *"auth + normal request in one call". What is *"one call"*? The way you ask this implies that right now you are doing it with *more than one call*. How do you do it right now? Show the code so it's clear which multiple calls you need to be compacted into one call.

Comment: The proxy server is not mine so I don't know what software they are using for it. The instructions for it just came with "The IP is x.x.x.x, the port is 10000 and the auth needs to be done on port 10001 with user x and pass y).

Comment: I see, that makes this more difficult as nothing so far can be said about the documentation of this. Well then at least show the code how you successfully interact with such requirements using PHP and the curl extension. That should provide some minimum answer if that is possible or not because most likely that would adhere to some standard procedure. Alternatively you could as well present the technical specification this authentication procedure with the proxy is based on. Any name of that scheme?

Comment: No sadly, I'm still waiting a reply from the sysadmins of my client